# Como criar lista dentro de lista

Tags: python-3.x, matriz

Estou tentando automatizar a criação de matrizes. Por exemplo, o problema me dá uma matriz qualquer e eu digito o número de linha e colunas e gero a matriz do tamanho que eu quero e não pré determinado como estou fazendo.

Segue abaixo minha tentativa:

```
import random
m = [[0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0]]
#PREENCHENDO A MATRIZ
for l in range(0, 5):
    for c in range(0, 5):
        m[l][c] = random.randrange(10)
#IMPRINDO A MATRIZ
for l in range(0, 5):
    for c in range(0, 5):
        print(f"[{m[l][c]:^5}]", end="")
    print()
print("MATRIZ GERADA.")
```

Do jeito que estou criando essa matriz fica inviável quando forem matrizes 1000x1000, por exemplo.

Eu gostaria de determinar as dimensões da `matriz(LINHA e COLUNA)` e cada elemento da matriz.

Comment: Em Python as lista são dinâmicas, mais pode tentar inicializar desta forma `m = [ [ 0 ] * 5 ] * 5`

Answer (score -1):

Para criar uma matriz com dimensões específicas e preencher cada elemento da matriz com um valor determinado, você pode utilizar duas estruturas de repetição aninhadas (for).

Por exemplo, veja o código abaixo, que cria uma matriz de tamanho n x m e preenche cada elemento da matriz com um valor aleatório entre 0 e 9:

```
import random

# Pede para o usuário informar o número de linhas e colunas da matriz
n = int(input("Informe o número de linhas da matriz: "))
m = int(input("Informe o número de colunas da matriz: "))

# Cria a matriz com n linhas e m colunas
matriz = []
for i in range(n):
    linha = []
    for j in range(m):
        linha.append(random.randrange(10))
    matriz.append(linha)

# Imprime a matriz
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(f"[{matriz[i][j]:^5}]", end="")
    print()
```

Nesse exemplo, a matriz é criada como uma lista de listas, onde cada lista interna representa uma linha da matriz. Para preencher cada elemento da matriz, utilizo duas estruturas de repetição aninhadas (for): a primeira itera sobre as linhas da matriz e a segunda itera sobre as colunas de cada linha. Dentro das estruturas de repetição, utilizo o método append para adicionar um novo elemento ao final da lista.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estva procurando. Mas encontrei a biblioteca NUMPY que trabalha melhor com matrizes. Por exemplo, para eu determinar uma matriz de tamanho já cohecido basta eu declarar a matriz com no explo abaixo: 

import random
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((3,4))
b = np.zeros((4,5))

for l in range(0,3):
    for c in range(0,4):
        a[l][c] = random.randrange(10)
print(a)  
print(f"A matriz gerada para A.")
print()

for l in range(0,4):
    for c in range(0,5):
        b[l][c] = random.randrange(10)
print(b)
print(f"A matriz gerada para B.")
print()